# Issue with email delivery from salesforce

Tags: email

I have been facing issue in delivery of emails from Salesforce as there is a delay in receiving of emails till 5-6 hours.

Also I have noticed that email logs tell me the error is "451 4.7.550 Access denied, please try again later. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653. [96.43.148.70] (AS22) ".

Please help!!

Comment: How are the emails sent? Via batch?

Comment: Emails are been sent through workflow email alerts